# How to iterating over multidimensional arrays with undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass?

Tags: arrays, ruby, null

I have array data like this:

```
work_list = {
    "data": {
        "1": {
            "team": "Design", 
            "members": nil, 
            "workload": {
                "process": {
                    "total": 50, 
                    "finish": 36, 
                    "un_finish": 14, 
                }
            } 
        },
        "2": {
            "team": "Account", 
            "members": 15, 
            "workload": {
                "process": {
                    "total": 30, 
                    "finish": 20, 
                    "un_finish": 10, 
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

I want to calculte total amount of work both team by:

```
list = work_list["data"]
count = 0

list.each do |num|
    num.each do |details|
       work = num["workload"]["process"]["total"]
       count += work
    end
end

puts "The total amount of works: #{count}"
```

The error here is: "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)"

Comment: `work_list` is a hash, not an array. Please edit to show the desired return value (Ruby object) for your example.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you're using `:` to build a hash:

```
"workload": {
  "process": {
    "total": 50, 
    "finish": 36, 
    "un_finish": 14, 
  }
}
```

Which is valid syntax in Ruby, but the keys of this hash are going to be symbols, not strings as expected, so you need to access the data of this hash by symbols:

```
data_hash = work_list[:"data"]
count = 0

data_hash.each do |index, data|
  work = data[:"workload"][:"process"][:"total"]
  count += work
end

puts "The total amount of works: #{count}"
```

If you want to use strings, you need to construct hash as following:

```
"workload" => {
  "process" => {
    "total" => 50, 
    "finish" => 36, 
    "un_finish" => 14, 
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, right. It works smooth when change to hash with symbol:

Answer (score 0):

You are iteration over a hash not array

```
list.each do |num, info|
  work = info["workload"]["process"]["total"]
  count += work
end
```